# Can a single link display/fade in captions for multiple images?

Tags: jquery, caption

I need help revealing the text caption of multiple images simultaneously by clicking on a single link using Jquery. I've been searching for a few days and haven't found anything that I can use. Can anyone point me in the right directions?

Comment: what is a text caption of an image?

Comment: Apologies for any confusing verbiage I used. I should have simply wrote "caption".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
$("#caption-link").on("click", function() {
    $("p.caption").fadeToggle();
});
```

..assuming you have the captions hidden to start with.

You can optionally set fade duration and animation type.
See the manual for .fadeToggle():
http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

(And for .toggle(): http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Ok, can you specify your question then? Is my answer giving you any help?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I've realized that I was being much to vague with my question. You'll have to forgive me since this is my first post here. I'd like to fade in each caption above it's corresponding image while slightly fading out each image. Can I still use the .toggle method to achieve this result? Cheers!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the fade requirement. This makes it clearer for later visitors. Welcome to SO by the way :)

Comment: Thank you for that last tip. This looks much simpler than I had anticipated. You've helped clear up a lot of questions that I previously had. Much obliged!